# Htaccess adding contents of shared file system in url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have setup a completely free website with x10hosting and freenom (.ml). In this website I have an `account` subdomain that uses the contents of the `/account/` directory in the `public_html` directory.

It all works fine, but when `http://account.lynk.ml/login` gets rewritten, it rewrites to `http://www.account.lynk.ml/home/MYUSERNAME/public_html/account/login.php`.

Is there anyway to make it have the url `http://account.lynk.ml/login`? Thanks in advance.

Subdomain code in htaccess:

```
# Account subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^account\.lynk\.ml$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/account/
RewriteRule (.*) /account/$1
```

I am new to subdomains, so don't expect much knowledge from me. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something such as the following should be what you might be looking for; It essentially will rewrite anything from `subdomain.example.com` or `subdomain.example.com/account` to `/login`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch ^/$ /login
RewriteRule ^login account/$1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /account/
RewriteRule ^account/(.*) /login/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This leaves the content in `/account` and makes the url appear as `/login`

Comment: Yes, but how would I change this to make it work with things other than login? How can I make this more universal? Thanks.

Comment: Universal how? It should do what your question asked.

Comment: Well, I want it to be able to not only with the login page, but with other pages. For example, `account.foo.com/register` would link to `register`, `account.foo.com/logout` would link to `logout`, etc. Instead of defining this multiple times, what about one to cover them all?

Comment: Then follow the example I've given and create them;  I've answered your original question, so if you're looking for something else then ask a new question.